# How to add new user as farm admin without powershell without central admin and without sql server

Tags: sharepoint-server, powershell, central-administration, sql-server, credentials

As we don't have the credentials to central admin, sql server whenever facing problem related to jobs and user profile service unable to do anything.

Currently the issue is every 1 min the support account got login failure and it is displaying in evernviewer.Due to this the particular support account keep on locking.

I suspect it is job related. But to disable job again powershell is needed.For powershell even I install in the server again it needs credential.

I tried below
1. Update farm credential using stsadm

- Afraid these accounts are related to service accounts too .. update with new password may affect existing service.

2.I tried adding user as farm admin, but still we need sql access for the new user mapping to SharePoint Server Admin Group.
http://blogs.devhorizon.com/reza/2012/03/07/adding-additional-farm-admins-to-an-existing-farm/

3.Checked in 14 hive logs but nowhere  log is maintained

4.Using stsadm we cant disable job only delete option available. To find out which job is running we have option to list out jobs.

As we dont have sql credential is there any way to add a user in Sql server using command prompt. Then we can connect to server and can add new user as farm admin

Help me to access sharepoint central admin also sql server

Thanks 
Jhanani

Answer (score 0):

No, I am afraid you cannot do that with an account without SQL logon credential.

When you run command prompt, the account which you are running in command must have proper permissions on SQL and have SQL logon credential.

For your requirement, you need to run commands using an existing farm account.

Comment: Hello @Kally_SPWX Could you please answer this question https://sharepoint.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1487/spwx-this-is-found-as-a-suffix-on-many-user-names